# How to reinstall the Intel Matrix Storage Manager option ROM

Tags: windows-xp, bios, raid, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision R5400 rack mount computer. It originally came with a the  Intel Matrix Storage Manager option ROM installed. But then we decided to remove the RAID drives and replace them with non-raid drives. Now for some reason the  Intel Matrix Storage Manager option ROM is no longer showing up at boot up (I used to be able to press CTRL-i to access it right after the PC BIOS finished booting but before Windows XP would boot).

How do I get the Intel Matrix Storage Manager option ROM boot option show again?

Do I have to re-install it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the RAID adapter have separate ports? you may just need to plug the drives into the proper ports on the board or enable RAID in bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option rom that you access at POST , is a hardware rom, it is either in the firmware for the motherboard, or the firmware for the card. It might be turned On or Off Via the BIOS.

Usually a Raid type of rom is not enabled or disabled via setting a drive unit as raid or not, nor does it change based on the existence of a drive or changes in an OS
It can be effected by the rom update items in the BIOS, where the motherboard bios scans the option roms.   It can be effected by the roms on the card, it can be effected by other roms on other cards.

Like many hardware options  it could be an item in the BIOS that is turned on or off.  When it is a Card item, they sometimes have jumpers or different firmware or firmware changes that can turn the rom itself on or off.

I dont know what exactally the situation here is list of possibles

If it was based only on a option card, and the card is not there, not working or seated improperly or has jumpers to disable it OR its rom.  (moved this up on the list, because from what I can tell, it was an option card)

If the rom screen is hidden (low possibility)  it is just harder to invoke it via the key command.  Dont hold the key keep hitting it over and over again.

Wrong command, it isnt I (rarely they move a key because of a conflict) , read the manuel < while reading check for a On/Off board Jumper settings, that might exist.

If the BIOS has been adjusted to shut it off (higher chance) Just go through the bios finding items that would turn it on (it is on the MB bios), for cards allow for a refreshing of the other hardware roms in the bios.

If a firmware change has been made to disable/remove it (happens but rare), Check for 2 firmware types for the motherboard or card bios at the manufactures site.

If the Rom for that has been damaged, not much you can do, but use it based only on the OS drivering, which works fine, except for when your not in that OS.

If the ROM(s) gets in a bios based Memory situation. in rare but painful cases, the amount of memory that each option rom uses , and the amount of memory that the bios leaves for it. This happens when you install it and the option rom never fit, or when changes are made to either rom and they both no longer fit. Also can happen when you add in another hard ROM that is used at post (another piece of hardware using a rom). Requires a different flash, or removing one board, or manufactures workaround.

If it is just a problem of installing, XP doesn't have that instantly available during install, you had to load a driver for "scsi" at install.

If you need more information, then more info about the system or what your seeing, or if there is a option card, what the option card is or was, what cards are in it, etc.

Comment: Hi, so I spoke with Dell regarding this and yes, a BIOS setting enables the RAID hardware, enabling the Intel Matrix Storage Manager option ROM. However, once this is enabled, and I create a RAID 1 configuration, my drives will be wiped. This sucks as I wanted to clone one of the drives by using RAID 1 (it's a long story as to why I would have thought of doing it this way). So instead they suggested using Norton Ghost. In any case, I'd say your response comes closest to answering my question.

Comment: Yes do a backup.   Honestly the data is not "wiped", by setting the drive for raid1 until you configure it different. But I would never switch it without a backup. having a good solid backup (or 2) then you have more freedom to configure.  There are so many ways to screw up, and so many thing going on, so i am not suggesting that you attempt it without a backup.  But if you ever are desperate and things are not going well, and your having problems, Don't Assume that the change has destroyed all the data.  Also helps to write down any settings and partition numbers as you create.

Answer (score 1):

"Matrix Storage Manager" is not a RAID controller like populating replacement drive from lat good one.
It has no advantage over soft mirror. The actual rebuild will hapen using Windows driver later. If you install MSM from Intel it might give you option to reconstruct array if it was ever there. Actually it should not wipe both disks (in theory) as RAID metadata is in the last sector(s) of a disk.

Comment: All RAID CONTROLLERS store metadata on last sector of the disk, each in their own format, they do not care it is MFT or EFI after.

Comment: Agreed for the "RST RAID configuration metadata" stored on the disk , my error.   . . . And makes retraction of the comment