# Reset Disks to Non-RAID in Intel Matrix Storage Manager

Tags: raid, sata

I have a Gigabyte S-Series motherboard based PC that was configured with two SATA drives.  The drives were NOT raided, but the RAID controller in BIOS was enabled - just no raid volumes created.  Windows is installed and was running fine.

Because of another unrelated problem I did a "Load Fail-safe defaults" options which turned off the BIOS raid setting.

After setting the BIOS back to RAID, the POST screen comes up like before with the Ctrl+I option to go into the raid configuration, but it fails to boot showing "Missing operating system".

If I press Ctrl+I and go into the RAID config, it says there's a RAID0(Stripe) volume with status "Failed", bootable "No".  The first drive status is "Non-RAID Disk" and the second "Member Disk(0)".  It's possible these drives used to be stripe raided many years ago but don't know for sure.

So the obvious question is how do I set things back to how they were without destroying anything?  The Reset Disks to Non-RAID gives a dramatic warning about "Resetting a disk causes all data on the disk to be lost".  Really? Even if the disk wasn't raided to start with?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: tYou sure better know if these were in a team or not. I would not change anything There , on a system that was just booting.  You reset the bios back to default,  so did you re-point to the Boot disk?  Use the boot menu and try to boot into the various disks without changing thier raid status.

Comment: @Psycogeek.  Thanks for answering.  Yes I tried disabling the Intel Matrix Storage Manager and booting from each drive, each time "Missing Operating System" error.  I know the RAID was enabled in the BIOS because the boot screen used to show the "Press Ctrl+I" message which only happens when that is enabled.  I know they weren't in a RAID volume because they're two 500gb drives and I had the first one partitioned into 250 + 125 + 125 which wouldn't be possible if they were.

Comment: some of this information may be valuable. http://superuser.com/questions/391159/how-to-reinstall-the-intel-matrix-storage-manager-option-rom/391230#comment442990_391230  I don't know what to tell you. mabey look at the disks from a cd or usb boot and try to understand what is going on.